# How can I use an ephemeral volume for a Docker container using an official MySQL image with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using an official MySQL docker image (https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/3288a66368f16deb6f2768ce373ab36f92553cfa/5.6/Dockerfile) with docker-compose and I would like its data to be wiped out upon restart.  The default is that it retains its data between container restarts.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mydb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: foo
```

When I use docker inspect on my container it shows its location on the host machine.  How can I instead have it store the data inside the container?  I do not want it to persist.

Answer (score 3):

When using `docker-compose`, the containers are not removed on `docker-compose stop` (or ctrl-c, or any other kind of interrupt/exit). Thus, if you're stopping the container, it's still going to exist the next time you start.

What you want is `docker-compose down` which, [according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) will "Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes". Note that only containers and networks are removed by default - you need to specify a command-line switch if you want to remove images or volumes.

Comment: To save people from having to look it up: `docker-compose down --volume`